# "Will be able to" in german

Tags: english-to-german, grammaticality, modal-verb, auxiliary-verb

I want to say in german something like "I will never be able to eat pig". Google translate tells me that the translation is "Ich werde niemals Schwein essen können". However, I see that there is a verb here (essen) that is stacked on top of two modal verbs (werden and konnen). Is this legal in german?

Comment: Yeah, and it is going much better as on English. However, German degrades quickly and the usage of "werden" is already nearly disappeared. They simply lost their *futur*.

Comment: I guess you mean _pork_, rather than _pig_. ;-)

Comment: I recall once reading an article which said that in general the human mind can handle three embeddings or iterations of a grammatical function but at four we can no longer grasp the overall structure.  I wish now I'd kept the citation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I will never be able to eat pig.*

> Ich werde niemals Schwein essen können.

This is a very good translation of the English sentence. However, it should read *pork* and *Schweinefleisch.*

*Werden* isn't a modal verb but an auxiliary. If it takes the infinitive, the result is the *Futur I* tense. Here the infinitive is *können*, a modal verb which takes another infinitive, *essen*. This stackup is okay.

---

You asked if a further stackup of modals is okay. Yes:

> Sie wird warten können müssen.

*She will have to be able to wait.* (She will need to be patient.)

Please note the order of the infinitives is just reversed in German.

Most stacked constructions make no sense though they are okay grammatically.

> Sie wird warten müssen können.

What's that even supposed to mean?

> Sie wird warten wollen sollen.

Word play?

Comment: *Sie wird warten gewollt haben können*?? *Sie wird warten gewollt haben können sollen*?. Stacking of auxiliaries and modals is theoretically possible on nearly infinitive levels. In practice, it tends, however, to get a bit too complicated to be understood.